# Sending Outlook email with Excel 365, using working older version of Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook, excel-365

I was using Excel VBA code to send multiple emails with multiple attachments from a list of email addresses and file names in an Excel table.

Excel VBA Source Link: https://github.com/sotirop/mergelook

Our IT team updated our MS Excel from MS 2016 to MS 365 and OS to Windows 10.

Now I get -

> 'Run-time error '287': application-defined or object-defined error'

At line

```
.To = .To & "; " & ActiveSheet.Cells(row, col).Value
```

[image: Type of VBA Error Screenshot]

[image: Line that gives an Error Screenshot]

Code that works on older version of Excel.

```vb
Sub sendEmailWithAttachments()

Dim OutLookApp As Object
Dim OutLookMailItem As Object
Dim myAttachments As Object
Dim row As Integer
Dim col As Integer

Set OutLookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.application")
row = 2
col = 1
ActiveSheet.Cells(row, col).Select
Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
    workFile = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & "message.oft"
    If FileExists(workFile) Then
        Set OutLookMailItem = OutLookApp.CreateItemFromTemplate(workFile)
    Else
        MsgBox ("message.oft file does not exist in the folder!" & vbNewLine & _
            "Also verify that the name is exactly 'message.oft'." & vbNewLine & _
            "Exiting...")
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Set myAttachments = OutLookMailItem.Attachments
    'Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
    Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveSheet.Cells(1, col))
        With OutLookMailItem
            If ActiveSheet.Cells(row, col).Value = "xxxFINISHxxx" Then
                'MsgBox ("Exiting...")
                Exit Sub
            End If
            If ActiveSheet.Cells(1, col).Value = "To" And Not IsEmpty(ActiveCell) Then
                .To = .To & "; " & ActiveSheet.Cells(row, col).Value
            ElseIf ActiveSheet.Cells(1, col).Value = "Cc" And Not IsEmpty(ActiveCell) Then
                .CC = .CC & "; " & ActiveSheet.Cells(row, col).Value
            ElseIf ActiveSheet.Cells(1, col).Value = "Bcc" And Not IsEmpty(ActiveCell) Then
                .BCC = .BCC & "; " & ActiveSheet.Cells(row, col).Value
            ElseIf ActiveSheet.Cells(1, col).Value = "Reply-To" And Not IsEmpty(ActiveCell) Then
                .ReplyRecipients.Add ActiveSheet.Cells(row, col).Value
            ElseIf ActiveSheet.Cells(1, col).Value = "attachment" And Not IsEmpty(ActiveCell) Then
                attachmentName = ActiveSheet.Cells(row, col).Value
                attachmentFile = Cells(ActiveCell.row, 17).Value & "\" & attachmentName
                If FileExists(attachmentFile) Then
                    myAttachments.Add Cells(ActiveCell.row, 17).Value & "\" & ActiveSheet.Cells(row, col).Value
                Else
                    MsgBox (Attachment & "'" & attachmentName & "'" & " file does not exist in the folder!" & vbNewLine & _
                        "Correct the situation and delete all messages from Outlook's Outbox folder before pressing 'Send Emails' again!" & vbNewLine & _
                        "Exiting...")
                    Exit Sub
                End If
            ElseIf ActiveSheet.Cells(1, col).Value = "xxxignorexxx" Then
                ' Do Nothing
            Else
                .Subject = Replace(.Subject, ActiveSheet.Cells(1, col).Value, ActiveSheet.Cells(row, col).Value)
                'Write #1, .HTMLBody
                .HTMLBody = Replace(.HTMLBody, ActiveSheet.Cells(1, col).Value, ActiveSheet.Cells(row, col).Value)
                'ActiveSheet.Cells(10, 10) = .HTMLBody
            End If
            
            'MsgBox (.To)
        End With
        'Application.Wait (Now + #12:00:01 AM#)
        
        col = col + 1
        ActiveSheet.Cells(row, col).Select
    Loop
    OutLookMailItem.HTMLBody = Replace(OutLookMailItem.HTMLBody, "xxxNLxxx", "<br>")
    OutLookMailItem.send
    col = 1
    row = row + 1
    ActiveSheet.Cells(row, col).Select
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: It is a really bad idea to use To / CC / BCC properties as intermediary variables. Introduce dedicated variables and build them instead. Once you are out of the loop, set the  To / CC / BCC properties without ever reading them.

Comment: Thanks Dmitry, I am very new to VBA, not sure how I can do that. Is it possible for you to help me with fixing code ?

Comment: Is Outlook running at backround?

Comment: Yes it is running at background

Comment: See the answer below

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on my comment above: it is a really bad idea to use `To` / `CC` / `BCC` properties as intermediary variables. Introduce dedicated variables and build them instead. Once you are out of the loop, set the `To` / `CC` / `BCC` properties without ever reading them.

```vb
    vTo = "";
    Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveSheet.Cells(1, col))
      ...
      If ActiveSheet.Cells(1, col).Value = "To" And Not IsEmpty(ActiveCell) 
      Then
         vTo  = vTo  & "; " & ActiveSheet.Cells(row, col).Value
         ...
    Loop
    OutLookMailItem.To = vTo
```

Comment: Thanks for taking out time to help me out. I am not sure where I need to add these code to make it work. I wonder if it is possible for you to show me?

I use following two files -
mergelook.xlsm and message.oft from following link to send my emails with multiple attachments

https://github.com/sotirop/mergelook

Comment: These are the lines that need to be modified in your code - instead of assigning to the `To` property, assign to a variable, then assign the `To` property when you are out of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using the `Recipients` property of the `MailItem` class to set recipients and then calling the [ResolveAll](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.recipients.resolveall) method which attempts to resolve all the `Recipient` objects in the `Recipients` collection against the Address Book. For example:

```
 Set myRecipient = MyItem.Recipients.Add("Eugene Astafiev")
 myRecipient.Resolve 
 If myRecipient .Resolved Then 
   myItem.Subject = "Test task" 
   myItem.Display 
 End If
```

See [How To: Fill TO,CC and BCC fields in Outlook programmatically](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/08/outlook-fill-recipients-programmatically/) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for taking out time to help me out. I need to pick up subject, to, cc, bcc, attachment etc from excel table. I can not use static subject.

I use following two files if you have a look you may get an idea -
mergelook.xlsm and message.oft from following link to send my emails with multiple attachments

https://github.com/sotirop/mergelook